# Can a static helper class be used for WebApi calls (from UI)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have X controllers that use a API site (WebApi). I have created an ApiHelper class. Which I use in these controllers. Now my question is this. Can I make this ApiHelper a static class? I think I can because the httpClient is instanced. Or do I overlook something, and does it need to be an instanced ApiHelper. (the use of static still confuses me sometimes). Example code below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public async Task<string> VersionDemo()
    {
        var response = await ApiHelper.Call("/api/config/version");
        var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var res = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(data.Result);
        return res;
    }
}

public class ConfigController : Controller
{
    private async Task<List<ConfigSetting>> GetGeneralConfigurationDemo()
    {
        var generalConfiguration = new List<ConfigSetting>();

        var response = await ApiHelper.Call("api/configuration/GetGeneralConfiguration");
        var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        generalConfiguration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ConfigSetting>>(data.Result);
        return generalConfiguration;
    }
}

public static class ApiHelper
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Call(string url)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var baseAdress = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseAddress"];
        string apiUrl = baseAdress + url;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, and actually you should re-use the HttpClient instance instead of disposing it on each use. I know this goes against everything we know about IDisposable, but [HttpClient is special.](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with your approach, it will work fine.  If you care about unit testing though then you will run into some difficulties.

Comment: Crowcoder thank you for you response and and the very interesting HttpClient post. Working on some improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Make base controller and hide http client as protected thing.

`public abstract class BaseController : Controller`
{

    `protected ApiHelper Api { get; set; }
}`

Then derive your controllers from BaseController

`public class ConfigController : BaseController {}`

`public class HomeController : BaseController {}`

Note : try not to use static classes cause they make your heap littered. They are allocated in "high-frequency" heap, which is never garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

There would be no problem to leave your class static as the `HttpClient` stays on the method scope and thus each call to your static method will use a different `HttpClient`. It would not be safe if you used a static member (field or property) as it would be shared by all the callers and you would need to synchronize the access (for a multi thread usage).

Answer (score 0):

After reading ([httpClient your are doing it wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) , [singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)) and subsequently testing. I ended up using the following code. Main goal is one httpClient application wide and avoid socket exhaustion.

In my controllers where I'm in need of a httpClient I use the HttpClientSingleton.Instance see below.

And here is a BaseController you can inherit from in your controllers that are going to use your API.

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public readonly string ApiBaseAdress = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseAddress"];
    public BaseController()
    {
        //Set as needed Servicepoint settings
        //string SecurityProtocolTypeFromConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecurityProtocolType"];
        //SecurityProtocolType fromConfig;
        //Enum.TryParse(SecurityProtocolTypeFromConfig, out fromConfig);
        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = fromConfig;

        //possible ServicePoint setting needed in some cases.                    
        //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        //ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 2000;
        //ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(false, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

And here is the HttpClientSingleton class:

```
  public sealed class HttpClientSingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> lazy = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => new HttpClient());

    public static HttpClient Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private HttpClientSingleton()
    {
    }
}
```

So putting it together. Here is an example of getting some loginfo from the API.

```
public class MyLogController : BaseController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> log(string requestId)
    {
        var url = ApiBaseAdress + string.Format("/api/runs/log/{0}", requestId);

        List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();

        var response = await HttpClientSingleton.Instance.GetAsync(url);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        logs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Log>>(result);

        return Json(logs);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can write a static helper class. If the name is `ApiHelper`, then add a `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` reference. When your app is initialized, call the class's `InitializeClient()` method, and you can call the `GetAsync()` method if you need. The code is below:

```
public static class ApiHelper
{
    public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

    public static void InitializeClient()
    {
        ApiClient = new HttpClient();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How we can add headers from the appsettings.json?